# Java: Switch default overriding try-catch

Tags: java, switch-statement, try-catch, default

**Package** `mylib`:

`Library` **class:**

```
package mylib;

import java.util.*;

class Library {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean isInfinite = true;
    int book_index;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Book[] myBooks = new Book[3]; // Create an array of books

    // Initialize each element of the array
    myBooks[0] = new Book("The Lover's Dictionary", "Levithan, D.", 211);
    myBooks[1] = new Book("White Tiger", "Adiga, A.", 304);
    myBooks[2] = new Book("Thirteen R3asons Why", "Asher, J.", 336);

    do {
        // Print book listing
        System.out.println("\n***** BOOK LISTING *****");
            for(int i = 0; i < myBooks.length; i++) {
                Book book = myBooks[i];
                System.out.println("[" + (i + 1) + "] " + book.sTitle + "\nAuthor: " +
                    book.sAuthor + "\nPages: " + book.iPages + "\nStatus: " + book.sStatus);
                System.out.print("\r\n");
            }

        // Select library action
        System.out.println("***** SELECT ACTION *****");
        System.out.println("B - Borrow a book" + "\nR - Reserve a book" +
            "\nI - Return a book" + "\nX - Exit program");
        System.out.print("\nEnter command: ");
        String sAction = input.nextLine();

        try {
            switch(sAction.toUpperCase()) { // Converts input to uppercase
                // Borrow a book
                case "B":
                    System.out.println("\n***** BORROW A BOOK *****");

                    System.out.print("Enter book index: ");
                    book_index = input.nextInt();
                    input.nextLine();

                    myBooks[book_index-1].borrowBook(); // Call method from another class
                break;

                // Reserve a book
                case "R":
                    System.out.println("\n***** RESERVE A BOOK *****");

                    System.out.print("Enter book index: ");
                    book_index = input.nextInt();
                    input.nextLine();

                    myBooks[book_index-1].reserveBook(); // Call method from another class
                break;

                // Return a book
                case "I":
                    System.out.println("\n***** RETURN A BOOK *****");

                    System.out.print("Enter book index: ");
                    book_index = input.nextInt();
                    input.nextLine();

                    myBooks[book_index-1].returnBook(); // Call method from another class
                break;

                // Exit the program
                case "X":
                    System.out.println("\nTerminating program...");
                    System.exit(0);
                break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("\nINVALID LIBRARY ACTION!");
                break;
            }
        }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException err) {
            System.out.println("\nINVALID BOOK INDEX!");
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException err) {
            System.out.println("\nINVALID INPUT!");
        }
    } while(isInfinite);
}
}
```

`Book` **class:**

```
package mylib;

class Book {
int iPages;
String sTitle, sAuthor, sStatus;

public static final String AVAILABLE = "AVAILABLE",
    BORROWED = "BORROWED", RESERVED = "RESERVED";

// Constructor
public Book(String sTitle, String sAuthor, int iPages) {
    this.sTitle = sTitle;
    this.sAuthor = sAuthor;
    this.iPages = iPages;
    this.sStatus = Book.AVAILABLE; // Initializes book status to AVAILABLE
}
// Constructor accepts no arguments
public Book() {
}

// Borrow book method
void borrowBook() {
    if(sStatus.equals(Book.AVAILABLE) || sStatus.equals(Book.RESERVED)) {
        sStatus = Book.BORROWED;

        System.out.println("\nBORROW SUCCESSFUL!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("\nBOOK IS UNAVAILABLE!");
    }
}

// Reserve book method
void reserveBook() {
    if(sStatus.equals(Book.AVAILABLE)) {
        sStatus = Book.RESERVED;

        System.out.println("\nRESERVE SUCCESSFUL!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("\nBOOK IS UNAVAILABLE!");
    }
}

// Return book method
void returnBook() {
    if(sStatus.equals(Book.AVAILABLE)) {
        System.out.println("\nBOOK IS ALREADY AVAILABLE!");
    }
    else if(sStatus.equals(Book.RESERVED)) {
        System.out.println("\nBOOK IS ALREADY RESERVED!");
    }
    else {
        sStatus = Book.AVAILABLE;
    }
}
}
```

When I enter an invalid book index, say 4, the error is caught and it prints "INVALID BOOK INDEX!"

However, when I enter a char or string for the book index, it prints "INVALID LIBRARY ACTION!" when it should be printing "INVALID INPUT!"

The default clause appears to override the catch?

Answer (score 1):

Your `sAction` variable is always a `String`, since `Scanner.nextLine()` returns `String`.

Therefore, your `default` statement is triggered, and it's reasonable to assume  the `InputMismatchException` catch will never execute.

See also the other [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) "next" methods if you'd like to fine-tune your input acceptance.

Example:

```
while (true) { // your infinite loop - better use a while-do instead of a do-while here
  String sAction = input.nextLine(); // we assign sAction iteratively until user "quits"
  // No try-catch: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is unchecked and you shouldn't catch it.
  // If it bugs, fix the code. 
  // No InputMismatchException either, as you don't need it if you use nextLine

  // your switch same as before 
}
```

Comment: Hi Mena, would you kindly fix the code? That is the only thing I am missing now. Thank you.

Comment: @user2539182 I won't fix your whole code but I can add a snippet in my answer - see edit shortly.

Comment: I have changed the infinite loop, looks better. Thanks. What exactly do you mean by "assign iteratively"?

Comment: @user2539182 By "assign iteratively" I mean to assign the `sAction` `String` to the user input ( `input.nextLine()` ) _within_ your infinite loop. This way, the actual looping happens when ever the user types a new input, and it stops in your case, whenever the user types "X".

Comment: Isn't the `String sAction = input.nextLine();` already _within_ the infinite loop? Sorry if I am lost in this.

Comment: @user2539182 Sorry you're totally right, I had misread the code for some reason. It is within the loop, as it should be :)

Comment: It's okay. The problem is still there though. Any other way to fix it?

Comment: @user2539182 ehm. What problem?

Comment: It's still not displaying the proper message. INVALID LIBRARY ACTION instead of INVALID INPUT. The error is being caught, but it is not displaying the intended message. The only change I made so far is the while-do infinite loop.

Comment: @user2539182 please read the edit in my answer again. You need to **remove** the `try`/`catch` statement and handle invalid inputs in your `default` statement. In short, you need to merge "invalid library action" with "invalid input", as there is no way an input mismatch exception will be thrown when you are expecting the input to be a `String` and manipulating it as such.

Comment: Hi, the try-catch is not for the `String sAction` but for the `int book_chosen`, hence the OutOfBounds and InputMismatch exceptions.

Comment: @user2539182 again, please **read** my answer. The OutOfBounds unchecked exception should **not** be caught. You need to fix your code instead.

Comment: I did read it, however, it did not work. I found my way around it though.

Answer (score 0):

Since the try-catch is for the `int book_chosen` and *not* for the `String sAction`, removing any of the catch-statement throws either OutOfBounds or InputMismatch error when I enter an int greater than 3 (OutOfBounds) or a char/string (InputMismatch) for the `int book_chosen` (`Enter book index:` ).

I have observed it is catching the errors when both catch statements are present, but not displaying the appropriate message. Since all are "invalid" inputs anyway, I found my way around it by just changing all the error prompts to `INVALID INPUT!`

**`Library` class:**

```
package mylib;

import java.util.*;

class Library {
static int book_index;
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

static void getIndex() {
    System.out.print("Enter book index: ");
    book_index = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create an array of books
    Book[] myBooks = new Book[3];

    // Initialize each element of the array
    myBooks[0] = new Book("The Lover's Dictionary", "Levithan, D.", 211);
    myBooks[1] = new Book("White Tiger", "Adiga, A.", 304);
    myBooks[2] = new Book("Thirteen R3asons Why", "Asher, J.", 336);

    while(true) {
        // Print book listing
        System.out.println("\n***** BOOK LISTING *****");
            for(int i = 0; i < myBooks.length; i++) {
                Book book = myBooks[i];
                System.out.println("[" + (i + 1) + "] " + book.sTitle +
                    "\nAuthor: " + book.sAuthor + "\nPages: " +
                    book.iPages + "\nStatus: " + book.sStatus);
                System.out.print("\r\n");
            }

        // Select library action
        System.out.println("***** SELECT ACTION *****");
        System.out.println("B - Borrow a book" + "\nR - Reserve a book" +
            "\nI - Return a book" + "\nX - Exit program");
        System.out.print("\nEnter command: ");
        String sAction = input.nextLine();

        try {
            switch(sAction.toUpperCase()) {
                // Borrow a book
                case "B":
                    System.out.println("\n***** BORROW A BOOK *****");
                    getIndex();
                    myBooks[book_index-1].borrowBook();
                break;

                // Reserve a book
                case "R":
                    System.out.println("\n***** RESERVE A BOOK *****");
                    getIndex();
                    myBooks[book_index-1].reserveBook();
                break;

                // Return a book
                case "I":
                    System.out.println("\n***** RETURN A BOOK *****");
                    getIndex();
                    myBooks[book_index-1].returnBook();
                break;

                // Exit the program
                case "X":
                    System.out.println("\nTerminating program...");
                    System.exit(0);
                break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("\nINVALID INPUT!");
                break;
            }
        }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException err) {
            System.out.println("\nINVALID INPUT!");
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException err) {
            System.out.println("\nINVALID INPUT!");
        }
    }
}
}
```

**`Book` class:**

```
package mylib;

class Book {
int iPages;
String sTitle, sAuthor, sStatus;

public static final String AVAILABLE = "AVAILABLE",
    BORROWED = "BORROWED", RESERVED = "RESERVED";

// Constructor
public Book(String sTitle, String sAuthor, int iPages) {
    this.sTitle = sTitle;
    this.sAuthor = sAuthor;
    this.iPages = iPages;
    this.sStatus = Book.AVAILABLE;
}

// Constructor accepts no arguments
public Book() {
}

// Borrow book method
void borrowBook() {
    if(sStatus.equals(Book.AVAILABLE) || sStatus.equals(Book.RESERVED)) {
        sStatus = Book.BORROWED;
        System.out.println("\nBORROW SUCCESSFUL!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("\nBOOK IS UNAVAILABLE!");
    }
}

// Reserve book method
void reserveBook() {
    if(sStatus.equals(Book.AVAILABLE)) {
        sStatus = Book.RESERVED;
        System.out.println("\nRESERVE SUCCESSFUL!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("\nBOOK IS UNAVAILABLE!");
    }
}

// Return book method
void returnBook() {
    if(sStatus.equals(Book.AVAILABLE)) {
        System.out.println("\nBOOK IS AVAILABLE!");
    }
    else if(sStatus.equals(Book.RESERVED)) {
        System.out.println("\nBOOK IS RESERVED!");
    }
    else {
        sStatus = Book.AVAILABLE;
        System.out.println("\nRETURN SUCCESSFUL!");
    }
}
}
```